# put the value inside the array inside a class

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I have a following class:

```
public class test100
{
     public string dateofbirth{ get; set; }
     public string phonenumber{ get; set; }

     public Name[] names { get; set; }

}
```

I want to assign value to names and then add that value in test100 class. I don't want to create the list. I just want to do this with an array. I want to put the values like this:

```
names[0] = {firstName="test1", MiddleName="test2", lastName="test3"}
```

and then add names[0] to test100 class.

How can I achieve this.

Comment: IMHO, use `List<T>` to do this.

Comment: Is it not possible to do without a list

Comment: Yes it's possible, why are you choosing an array?

Comment: If you use a `List<T>` you can do something like: `Name.Add(new Name(){.firstName="somebody"});` Also if you don't know how many `Name` you are using, you will not know the size of the array, using a `List<T>` you don't need to know the size.

Comment: I am trying to create a JSON and I want something like "test100": [
   {
    
    "names": {
     
     "personDetails": {
      "firstName": "test1",
      :MiddleName=
     },  I think this is only possible with arrays not list

Comment: with list, I will get a square bracket

Comment: If you're trying to create a `json` object, you can create a list of these names and then use a library like `Newtonsoft.JSON` to serialize your data, why re-create the wheel when it's already been done for you?

Comment: lists and arrays "will" give you a square bracket since it represents an array/list.

Comment: How can I get curly brackets instead of square brackets

Comment: @rimi - Did you try serializing a list and an array and see what difference you get? Here's the result of me serializing a list and an array of three integers: `[1,2,3]` and `[1,2,3]`. There is no difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize the array while initializing the class itself

```
var data = new test100
{
  dateofbirth = "22-03-1997",
  phonenumber = "1-223344",
  names = new Name[] 
  {
    new Name {firstName="test1", MiddleName="test2", lastName="test3"}
  }
}
```

Problem with this is that you haven't defined any size for your `names` array. So you can create instance of your class, define the size of that array and then insert the object to that array

```
var data = new test100();
data.names = new Name[10];
Name name = new Name {firstName="test1", MiddleName="test2", lastName="test3"};
data.names[0] = name;
```